# Error on retrieve field from database using Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Have a controller function:

```
public function pageedit($id)
{
    $page = Pages::where('pgeID','=',121)->get();
    return view('admin.pageedit')->with('page',$page);
}
```

And a simple view:

```
@extends('admin')

@section('content')
    @include('/partials/adminpageheader')
    Edit Page {{ $page }}
@endsection
```

When I run this, I get the output as follows:

```
Intranet Web Control Panel (Pages)
Admin Home - Admin Home Page
Edit Page
[{"pgeID":"121","pgeActive":"0","pgeContent":"1","pgeMainLevel":"6","pgeLevel":"1","pgeParent":"6","pgeOrder":"3","pgeTitle":"Employee Assistance Program","pgeHeader":"Null","pgeBody":Employee Assistance Program that all employees can access 24\/7. The website, www.assist.com has an amazing amount of information available. If you are looking for training, articles, resources and more, check them out. The use","pgeNav":null,"pgeContents":"Null","pgeCallOut":"Null","pgeEditor":"Null","pgeTitleDRAFT":"Null","pgeTemplateDRAFT":null,"pgeNavDRAFT":null,"pgeContentsDRAFT":"Null","pgeCallOutDRAFT":"Null"}]
```

So I know it is pulling the data correctly.  But when I try to display JUST the page title (pgeTitle) I get an undefined property error if I try {{ $page->pgeTitle }} and an undefined index error if I try {{ $page['pgeTitle'] }}

I know it has to be something simple I am forgetting, but I will be danged if I can figure out what it is. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `->get()` use `->first()`. This will return a single instance as opposed to the collection, which is the difference between having to use an array accessor and not.

```
$page = Pages::where('pgeID','=',121)->first();
                                         ^
                                    first==single
                                get==array collection
```

Answer (score 0):

`$page` is an array, where the index is numeric as far as i can tell, so you should do:

```
{{$page[0]->pgeTitle}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same answer than Taxicala, but I'd suggest you to use ->first() method instead of get, since you're looking for only 1 row.

```
$page = Pages::where('pgeID','=',121)->first();
```

Comment: Choose the below answer as correct only because by using first, I no longer address it as $page[0]->pgeTitle, jusr $page->pgeTitle

Comment: @KeithClark not a problem!